# Input text color differs from idle color

Tags: html, css, contact-form

Okay, so, I'll try to explain this the best I can...

I'm working on styling a contact formula.

I've set my input focus text to have a color of white.

But when I click away from my form, the inputted text color goes to black.

My question is, how do I style the inputted text color when I click of my form?

Example below:

```css
* {
  background: red;
}

.contact-formula {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 32.5%;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
  resize: none;
  height: 15vh;
}

label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-formula">
  <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="First Name" autofocus><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="email"><br>
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm hoping someone can point me towards what I'm overlooking/missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `input[type=text] {color: white;}`

```css
* {
  background: red;
}

.contact-formula {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 32.5%;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
}

input[type=text] {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
  resize: none;
  height: 15vh;
}

label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-formula">
  <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="First Name" autofocus><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="email"><br>
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The font-size is also changed on focus out.

Comment: Ah, I missed that one haha. How would I go about having the font-size stay the same?

Comment: Just add those styles to the input instead of `input:focus`

Comment: @ksav Thanks for the help, I accepted your anser as the solution. Also, do you know how to increase the font-size of the inputted text of textarea by any chance?

Comment: Look for `textarea` and add `font-size: 3vh`

Answer (score 2):

**It's because you're using the `:focus` pseudo-class.**
If you remove the `:focus`, then it will work fine.

```css
* {
  background: red;
}

.contact-formula {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 32.5%;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
  resize: none;
  height: 15vh;
}

label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

textarea,
input {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-formula">
  <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="First Name" autofocus><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="email"><br>
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right! All though, the font-size still changes when I click away.. What am I missing?

Comment: @treadwell Huh, that's odd. It doesn't change for me... I don't see any problem with the code either... As long as the `font-size` rule is the same as for the `placeholder` class, it should be fine.

Comment: I think it was because I didn't define input as input[type=text], that seemed to fix it! But thanks for your helps regardless, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

you should juste remove the `:focus` on `textarea, input` :

```css
* {
  background: red;
}

.contact-formula {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 32.5%;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
  width: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .25vh solid orange;
  resize: none;
  height: 15vh;
}

label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

textarea,
input {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-formula">
  <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="First Name" autofocus><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="email"><br>
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```